# Max function vs using all_sequences in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a sequence defined that I use specifically for a column in a table. increment by 1 and caching 10. This is a huge table, doesn't have an index on the column. I want to know the maximum value of the column. since max function will take a lot of time, I am looking at using the `last_number` column of `all_sequences` view. Is that the right approach? especially with caching involved? So if the table is insert-only and no deletes, and 1000 is the max value inserted, will I see `last_number` as 1000?

Edit:
I want to know this after the database is unavailable for regular traffic. No other connections when I run this.

Comment: That's not generally going to work.  What if a transaction has rolled back or what if some other session has inserted a row but not committed yet?  Why do you want to know the `max` value?  Are you sure that you don't want to use the `currval` of the sequence (which would tell you the last value that you got from the sequence in the current session).

Comment: Do you want to know the maximum value in that column or the number of rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to know the max value of a column, probably the fastest way is to add an index on that column; that way the query only needs to fetch the last block from the index to determine the maximum value - you just need to ensure that your query is written correctly to take advantage of Oracle's MIN/MAX optimisation (e.g. `SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable` should do it - but check the execution plan first)

As Justin says, the sequence generator is highly unlikely to be useful for this purpose - not just because of rollbacks, but also other sequence features like caching, incrementing and how they behave in a RAC environment mean that `last_number` is usually expected to be much higher than the actual max value of the column.